# Cross-platform compiling with C++

Tags: c++

I'm making my first real C++ game that I'd like to be able to run on Windows, Mac, and Linux. I already understand that to accomplish that, your libraries need to support those platforms (I'm only using GLFW). My questions are:

1. I'm completely lost when it comes to compiling. I understand that you can't use MinGW, due to it's Windows-only support. What would I be using?
2. In terms of an IDE, which is the best to use in this scenario? I'm currently using Visual Studio, but I've heard I can't do cross-platform with that. I also have Code::Blocks, and wouldn't mind switching.
3. What are the best practices for cross-platform compiling? Am I safe doing everything on Windows, or should I set up Linux and Mac virtual machines?

Comment: You can't really claim to support a platform if you've never actually *run* your program on that platform.  You'll need to have access to Linux and Mac systems for testing.

Answer (score 1):

If your code does not have any dependency on any system level libraries such as networking, I/O, etc, then as long as you stick to the ISO C++ standard, it should be portable across different platforms. Even if you really need to access some low level system libraries which are OS-dependent, on Windows you can use Cygwin to emulate the behaviors of Unix-like systems such as Linux and OS X. Then you can use GCC to compile your code so that any dependency on system library can be resolved. For the IDE, Eclipse CDT may be an option since it runs on all three platforms. Using virtual machine or real machine to build separate code base for all platforms is another option but you need that anyway when you go for testing your code.

Comment: You can also use a number of the Boost libraries across all platforms, which can help with compatibility as well (e.g. file path handling, threading, network IO (asio))

Answer (score 0):

Targeting all three for your first C++ game is ambitious, primarily because the development "toolchains" are typically so different on each platform.  You can attempt to use something like the gcc compiler and Eclipse on all three, but more typically you end up using:

- Visual C++/Visual Studio on Windows
- GCC on Linux/(various IDEs)
- GCC or Clang on OS X/Xcode IDE

The best solution I've seen used for wrangling all this from one codebase is the [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) toolkit.  By describing your codebase in the CMake format, it will auto-generate (and keep up-to-date) platform/IDE-specific solution/projects/makefiles for you, and a number of tools to help set up automated builds, build dashboards, automated testing, etc.

Alternatively, you could bail on the fine-grain control of C++ and code it up in Java, which is much more unified across these operating systems (but, of course, has it's own sets of issues.)

Answer (score 0):

How to develop Cross-Platform! (The Guide)

1. Never use any functions that are specific to a platform (e.g. the  include is out of the question)
2. Always use some form of build-tools. I highly suggest NOT to use AutoMake if you want it to work on windows (you can shoot me now). CMake is good as long as you trust their extensions.
3. Compilers have their own specific errors. Really! A nice practice (when available) is to use the same compiler on as many platforms as possible. Luckily for you, LLVM/Clang is available on all three of the big targets! I'd suggest using it for the project if you aim for proper cross-platforming.
4. You want an editor that Minds-Its-Own-Business (tm). For example, Visual Studio (and codeblocks!) will FORCE their build system upon you. I suggest vim (a lightweight console/graphical (with gvim) text editor) or geany (lightweight IDE with plugins)
5. Emulators are EVIL! Stay away from MinGW, Wine, Cygwin and similar. No, really.
6. Compile your libraries from source when you can, using your compiler. It's just safer, and lets you fine-tune the features. (GLFW can do that!)

This will hopefully help. On a side note, how's GLFW?